# Error restarting mongo.service trying to add multiple bind ip in mongodb 4.2

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-replica-set

I am using **mongodb 4.2** version. I am trying to make replicaset following [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/create-a-mongodb-replica-set/) article but when I try to bind like in this screenshot

[image]

mongo service fails to restart and show errors like:

[image]

**any ways to fix this? have tried all the Q&A about mongo from stackoverflow**

Answer (score 3):

Try this :- bindIp: 127.0.0.1;192.168.1.178;192.168.1.111
replace comma(,) to semicolon(;)

Comment: I am gonna try it, but works when i use bind_ip_all i.e. 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** My answer only addresses the problem of a failing mongodb service after *system reboot*. If your service is failing after a *service restart* on a running system you have a different problem.

The problem is that at the time of mongodb service start the IP address is not yet available.

To fix this you can set up a systmed service overwrite rule:

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.d
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.d/ip_bind.conf
```

Add the following lines

```
[Unit]                                                                           
After=network-online.target
```

This will overwrite the default rule `After=network.target`. On my system (Ubuntu 20.04) the default mongodb service configuration is located in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as `bindIp` parameter accepts string, the syntax of your value looks fine.

You can get the complete output of your service using `journalctl` command, you can use the following command,

```
journalctl -xe -u mongod.service
```

The logs there, will show you the complete error logs.

You can also check the logs of `mongod process` which is configured in your configuration file under `systemLog.path`.

You should be using the only IP Addresses at which the `mongod will be listening`, so you can check your IP addresses once again.

Below is my configuration file,

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.100.101
   port: 27018
```

It works just fine.

Comment: sorry, but doesn't work I tried and please see the question it is similar i guess.

Comment: @sssanjaya Please add the logs to the question, to get a more clear view of the issue you are facing. I want to see what the mongod process complains about